# Get corresponding value for particular index/key in Pandas after converting wide to long

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, melt

I am planning to implement the below logic to get the student score.

Find students getting more than 60 marks

And then get that student marks too based on Subject Student Key!

**Input Data**

```
data = [['Maths', 100,80,20], ['Science', 80,20,10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Subject', 'Student A','Student B','Student C'])
df.set_index("Subject",inplace=True)


         Student A  Student B   Student C
Subject         
Maths      100       80         20
Science     80       20         10
```

**Get Students getting more than 60 marks**

```
df=df[df.gt(60)]
rank_df = df.rank(axis=0,method='average',pct=False,ascending=False)
marks_list = []
for i in range(0,len(rank_df)):
    label_series = rank_df.iloc[i,:]
    labels_notna = label_series.sort_values(ascending=True)[label_series.notna()].index
    marks_list.append(",".join(labels_notna))
df['Student gt 60'] = marks_list


new_df = df['Student gt 60'].str.split(',', expand = True)
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
new_df.columns=["Subject","Top 1","Top 2"]
new_df = pd.melt(new_df, id_vars=['Subject'], value_name='Student')
data= new_df[["Subject","Student"]]
data.loc[~data["Student"].isna()]

    Subject Student
0   Maths   Student A
1   Science Student A
2   Maths   Student B
```

I am planning to get an associated score for the Subject/Student key in the same data frame but not able to work it out.

**Required Output:**

```
Subject Student Score
0   Maths   Student A   100
1   Maths   Student B   80
2   Science Student A   80
```

Could somebody help me with some pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend stacking the dataframe first to get a MultiIndex Series (with the subject in the first level and the students in the second level) and then index this Series selecting all students with a sufficient score:

```
df_stacked = df.stack()
df_stacked[df_stacked.gt(60)]
# Out: 
# Subject           
# Maths    Student A    100
#          Student B     80
# Science  Student A     80
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you. I made my logic so complicated. Never thought it was so easy

Comment: You are welcome! Yeah, pandas is a great tool with many easy and straightforward methods for reshaping, pivoting etc. And honestly, even after several years of intense pandas usage, I still have to look up the functionality of pivot, melt etc regularly. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, orient your data the way you eventually want it:

```
vertical = df.unstack()
```

That gives you:

```
           Subject
Student A  Maths      100
           Science     80
Student B  Maths       80
           Science     20
Student C  Maths       20
           Science     10
```

Then simply:

```
vertical[vertical > 60]
```

Gives you the final result:

```
           Subject
Student A  Maths      100
           Science     80
Student B  Maths       80
```

You can do `reset_index()` on that to make it look more like your example output.